# NArgMin with Root functions

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, fitting, warning-messages

I'm trying to minimize an error function `sumt` to find some parameters `S, s0, si` :

```
Ris[S_?NumericQ, s0_?NumericQ, si_?NumericQ, so_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ] = 
 RR /. Solve[((8 RR*S ((2 RR^2)/R^3 - s0))/R^3 + 
       8 π RR si + (8 π RR^2 so)/(R^3 + RR^3)^(
       1/3)) == 0, RR][[4]]
ri = {54, 55, 62, 66, 62, 66, 71, 75, 77, 79, 94, 89, 99, 113, 124, 
  123, 140, 157, 163, 176}
re = {72, 74, 82, 83, 90, 97, 104, 113, 115, 126, 136, 143, 158, 171, 
  185, 192, 218, 226, 246, 270}
Rdata = (re^3 - ri^3)^(1/3);
tableerror = 
  Table[(Ris[10^S, s0, si, 1, Rdata[[i]]] - 
      ri[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[ri]}];
sumt[S_?NumericQ, s0_?NumericQ, si_?NumericQ] = 
  Total[tableerror];
NArgMin[{sumt[S, s0, si], 
  8 < S < 11 && 0.001 < s0 < 0.1 && 0.001 < si < 10}, {S, s0, si}]
```

But this doesn't work and I get the message:

> NArgMin::nrnum :  The function value -2.52192*10^6-1.90614*10^6 I is not a real number at {S,s0,si} = {8.98306,0.0730269,6.67086}. >>

I suspect that it is because the `Root` function in my `Ris` function.
Is it the issue ? And how could I fix this ?

Comment: `rayoninterne` is undefined.

Comment: @BobHanlon sorry I just fixed that

Comment: I think the problem is that `sumt` is not a real function.

Comment: Check out `Table[(Ris[10^S, s0, si, 1, Rdata[[i]]] - ri[[i]])^2, {i, 1, 
  Length[ri], 10}, {S, 8, 11}, {s0, 0.001, 0.1, 0.05}, {si, 0.001, 10,
   5}]` — You've got complex numbers.